# MySQL: Display single row as column (simply, via SELECT)

Tags: mysql, sql, unpivot

Is there a simple way to SELECT a single row in MySQL and have it transposed so that the column headers are listed in a left-hand column and the values are listed in the right-hand column?

Example:

Instead of this:

```
SELECT * FROM sock_table LIMIT 1;

+---------+--------------+------------+
| sock_id | smell_factor | hole_count | 
+---------+--------------+------------+
| S000123 | 7.2          | 1          |
+---------+--------------+------------+
```

...you could do something like this:

```
SELECT TRANSPOSE(*) FROM sock_table LIMIT 1;

sock_id      S000123
smell_factor     7.2
hole_count         1
```

For those familiar with python - pandas, `df.loc[0]` (where 0 is the index position) automatically performs this function.

This would be for a table with dozens of column headers, so typing out the headers is more of a hassle than it's worth.

Comment: Use `UNION` of queries for each column.

Comment: There's nothing built-in that does this.

Comment: Just updated my question to note that typing out column names would defeat the purpose.  And maybe @Barmar is right re: lack of native functionality.

Comment: If you don't want to type all the subqueries for each column, you could create a stored procedure that generates dynamic SQL from the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` table.

Answer (score 3):

In MYSQL, use `UNION ALL` to unpivot:

```
(select 'stock_id' col, stock_id val FROM stock_table order by id limit 1)
union all (select 'smell_factor' col, smell_factor val FROM stock_table order by id limit 1)
union all (select 'hole_count' col, hole_count val FROM stock_table order by id limit 1)
```

Important notes:

- this requires one subquery per column
- `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is not stable; you need a deterministic `ORDER BY` clause - I assumed that column `id` can be used to order the records
- The datatypes of the values need to be consistent - you might need to `cast` them if that's not the case

---

**EDIT**

Actually, very recent versions of MySQL (8.0.19 or higher) make it possible to express this with `values row()` and `lateral`, which shortens the query:

```
select x.* 
from (select * from mytable order by id limit 1) t,
lateral (values
    row ('stock_id', t.stock_id), 
    row ('smell_factor', t.smell_factor),
    row ('hole_count', t.hole_count)
) x(col, val)
```

Comment: Thanks for posting GMB, but that sample table in my question was way oversimplified, it will have significantly more columns.

Comment: @elPastor: so you need more more `union all` members (one per column).

Comment: Eeesh, ok.  Sounds like the juice ain't worth the squeeze.  Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: @elPastor: see my edit for an alternative if you are running MySQL 8.0.14 or higher.

Comment: Thanks, but again, I'd have to type dozens of columns, I'm looking for a simple function, which I'm guessing doesn't exist.

Comment: @elPastor: no. In pure SQL, you need to enumerate the column names, one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `sock_table` is composed of those three columns, and `sock_id` as the primary key of the table so as to use within the `ORDER BY` Clause. Then, consider using this Dynamic Query Statement in order to get unpivoted result :

```
SET @sql = NULL;
       
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
       CONCAT( 
       '( SELECT "',column_name,'" AS col_name, ',column_name,' AS value 
            FROM ',table_name,' ORDER BY sock_id LIMIT 1 ) ' )
       SEPARATOR 'UNION ALL ')
  INTO @sql     
  FROM information_schema.columns c
 WHERE table_name = 'sock_table'
 ORDER BY ordinal_position;      


PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=437aa3a448924e1b91bf54418570eaa0)</kbd>

This case, no need to individually specify each column name.